# php display next value after some delay

Tags: php, arrays, delay, timedelay

So I have an array

```
$super = array(8,9,10,11,12,20,21);
```

I want to display first value for one hour in my website

after one hour  display second one and etc.

after array reaches the end "21"   it resets and starts to display first value

```
echo $super [0]
```

wait for one hour   $super change to

```
$super[1]
```

next hour

```
 $super[2]
```

and etc.

after

```
$super == $super[21]
```

reset

```
 $super to  $super[0]
```

I could use next(), current(), reset() functions, but I can't figure out how to loop them with delay.

Comment: On the first page load, store the current `time()` into the user's session. Then use that value as the baseline for your time calculations. After `$num_hours` hours has passed, do `echo $super[$num_hours];`. Add in logic for roll over.

Comment: $super array will always have these values or it can change? and if you say for what you need to do that here, then somebody may come up with a solution

Comment: @zamil the values can change, array will get more values

Comment: @nickb  can't use session for this

Comment: Then use a cookie, you need persistence. Unless you're going to expect to keep an open connection to your server for hours, which is not only impossible with most if not all shared hosts, but a waste of resources.

Comment: what if the page is not refreshed for several hours.should it change or should it change after the reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enjoy server-side static version:

```
$super = array(8,9,10,11,12,20,21); // Array can be extended
$h = date('H') ; //Current hour. Server time

$start_day_element = 0 ; //Offset, from what element days start.

echo $super[($h + $start_day_element)%count($super)] ;
```

But of course, page must be refreshed to see updated value.

Answer (score 0):

its awkward

user javascript settimeout to execute a js function with ajax

```
eg:setTimeout("somefun();", 5000);
```

where 5000 is the time delay

```
function somefun(){
    $("#msgSpan").load("site.com/somepage.php");
}
```

where "#msgSpan" is the id of the element where you display the array values

implement the logic to return array values accordingly in somepage.php

u can use php sessions to record current array index and for every next request you increment the array index